# CPU Thermal Margin is very low

Tags: linux, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

My computer is restarting  unexpectedly for some days. First I though Its an os issue. I gone through all the sys log and didn't find any clue. Then gone through bios event log. Nothing was there too. Then at the hardware monitor section I saw *CPU Thermal margin* is very low. Like 1°-3° celsius. And CPU temperature (ICS Temp) is about 83°-86°

After googling a bit I found temperature margin seems like a margin that CPU is not designed to operate if temperature goes beyond it.
So I though I would monitor this. But couldn't find any tool on Ubuntu 12.04.

So,

1. How do I reduce CPU temperature? I have already cleaned all the pc component. All fans are functional?
2. How do I monitor CPU temperature? All the temperature monitor applet I found monitors M/B temperature. All of them shows temperature 54°. which I see is M/B temp on BIOS. But CPU is more than 80° on BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

### Monitoring/Getting current temperature

The classic tool for this kind of monitoring under Linux is `sensors`:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect
```

Answer "y" to all questions and load any modules suggested by the last step using (`sudo modprobe module_name`), make sure the settings are loaded and then then run sensors:

```
sensors
```

That should show you output similar to this:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +53.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +58.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

i8k-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Right Fan:   87690 RPM
CPU:          +58.0°C
```

---

Depending on your system, there are various files that can contain this information. One of these should give you your temperature:

```
cat /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp?_input
```

or

```
cat /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THM0/temperature
```

or

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/ips/cpu_temp
```

or

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input
```

or

```
cat cat /sys/bus/platform/devices/coretemp.0/temp2_input
```

---

### Reducing CPU temperature.

1. Is your CPU always running at top speed? Try setting another [scaling governor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling#Scaling_governors). Your options are:

   - **Performance** keeps the CPU at the highest possible frequency
   - **Powersave** keeps the CPU at the lowest possible frequency
   - **Userspace** exports the available frequency information to the user level (through the /sys file system) 
           and permits user-space control of the CPU frequency
   - **Ondemand** scales the CPU frequencies according to the CPU usage (like does the userspace frequency scaling 
          daemons, but in kernel)
   - **Conservative** acts like the ondemand but increases frequency step by step

   Personally, I use `ondemand` and recommend it. The Ubuntu wiki [warns of certain problems](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Quantal_Hardware#CPU_and_motherboard), but I have never had any trouble with it. To use the ondemand governor do:

   sudo echo ondemand >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
2. If the above does not help, you might have a hardware issue. Since you have already checked the fan, the next most likely culprit is the [thermal paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_grease). If you've had your computer for a while, it is likely that the paste between the heat sink and the CPU has gotten old and you should change it:

   - Open the machine, remove the fan and heatsink from the CPU.
   - Remove the old thermal paste from **both the CPU and the heatsink**, ideally using a cotton swab with [isopropyl alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol#Solvent). For the heatsink, you can also use a knife or similar to scrape off the paste before cleaning the rest with the alcohol. I don't recommend you try and scrape it off the CPU though, just use the cotton swab.
   - Once you have cleaned the old paste away, apply a *small* amount to the center of the CPU and then re-attache the heatsink. Since the heatsink will be held down tightly against the CPU, it will also spread the paste around uniformly. Make sure you don't use a lot of paste since that might cause it to overflow around the edges of the heatsink.

   For a (very) detailed tutorial on changing your thermal paste, see [here](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/274).